# If $R$ is a Boolean ring which is in fact a field, then it must be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields, boolean-ring

> Suppose $R$ is a Boolean ring ($\forall r \in R, r^2 =r$) which is in fact a field.  Show it then must be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$.

I already managed to show that every Boolean ring is commutative and that it has characteristic two. $\forall r \in R$ we have $r+r=0$. By a theorem 6 chapters ahead, we can already  say that  $R \cong \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z. $ ( classification of finite fields). I am however not really allowed to use this yet. I cannot really construct an isomorphism if I can't describe it. How would I construct this?

To construct an isomorphism I think I need to show that $|R|=2$. So far I am not really allowed to use any characterisation theorems yet.

Comment: $r^2=r$ means $r(r-1)=0$; in a field, that means $r=0$ or $1$

Comment: I am at the start of the course when we do not have any powerful tools available yet, @ChrisCuster week 1 basically. We know the definition of a ring homomorphism,  We have shown some properties of domains, rings and fields, I think the tip from Tanner works.

Comment: I think you're right, since a field is an integral domain.  My idea was off, probably for a couple reasons, like we don't assume finiteness.

Comment: To fiend the duplicate, I just searched “Boolean field”. Please perform a search like this first next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only idempotents in a field are $0$ and $1$. Hence, the only field that is also a Boolean ring is the one with two elements, which is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.